# Selenium WebDriver - How to get a web page contents without opening it in browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to save the contents of a web page but do not want to open it in any browser.
Is there any way in Selenium WebDriver where i can get the contents through the web link.

Comment: If all you want to do is get the contents of a webpage, maybe `wget` or `curl` would be more appropriate than Selenium?

Comment: All you want seems to be a headless browser. or u can also use any httpclient and parse the responses generated from them for contents but they might be in html / xml / json.

Comment: Do we have some solution in selenium web driver as that is the only tool i need to use.

Comment: Use headless browser as suggested by @Saifur ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that using headless. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is one of the best options. A sample example taken from [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/pizza.js)

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
url = 'http://lite.yelp.com/search?find_desc=pizza&find_loc=94040&find_submit=Search';
page.open(url, function (status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
console.log('Unable to access network');
} else {
    var results = page.evaluate(function() {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('address'), pizza = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    pizza.push(list[i].innerText);
}
    return pizza;
});
    console.log(results.join('\n'));
}
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't use Selenium for this.

Use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

100% headless, and does not require any 3rd party programs, unlike selenium, to get the page content.